# Mix and match stateful computations within the State monad

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

The state of my program consists of three values, `a`, `b`, and `c`, of types `A`, `B`, and `C`. Different functions need access to different values. I want to write functions using the `State` monad so that each function can only access the pieces of the state that it needs to access.

I have four functions of the following types:

```
f :: State (A, B, C) x
g :: y -> State (A, B) x
h :: y -> State (B, C) x
i :: y -> State (A, C) x
```

Here is how I call `g` within `f`:

```
f = do
    -- some stuff
    -- y is bound to an expression somewhere in here
    -- more stuff
    x <- g' y
    -- even more stuff

    where g' y = do
              (a, b, c) <- get
              let (x, (a', b')) = runState (g y) (a, b)
              put (a', b', c)
              return x
```

That `g'` function is an ugly piece of boilerplate that does nothing but bridge the gap between the types `(A, B, C)` and `(A, B)`. It is basically a version of `g` that operates on a 3-tuple state, but leaves the 3rd tuple item unchanged. I am looking for a way to write `f` without that boilerplate. Maybe something like this:

```
f = do
    -- stuff
    x <- convert (0,1,2) (g y)
    -- more stuff
```

Where `convert (0,1,2)` converts a computation of type `State (a, b) x` to type `State (a, b, c) x`. Likewise, for all types `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`:

- `convert (2,0,1)` converts `State (c,a) x` to `State (a,b,c) x`
- `convert (0,1)` converts `State b x` to `State (a,b) x`
- `convert (0,2,1,0)` converts `State (c,b) x` to `State (a,b,c,d) x`

**My questions:**

1. Is there a better solution than putting state values in tuples? I thought about using a monad transformer stack. However, I think that only works if, for any two functions `f` and `g`, either `F` ⊆ `G` or `G` ⊆ `F`, where `F` is the set of state values needed by `f` and `G` is the set of state values needed by `g`. Am I wrong about that? (Note that my example does not satisfy this property. For example, `G` = `{a, b}` and `H` = `{b, c}`. Neither is a subset of the other.)
2. If there is no better way than tuples, then is there a good way to avoid the boilerplate I mentioned? I am even willing to write a file with a bunch of boilerplate functions (see below) as long as the file can be automatically generated once and then forgotten about. Is there a better way? (I have read about lenses, but their complexity, ugly syntax, enormous set of unnecessary features, and seeming reliance on Template Haskell are off-putting. Is that a misconception of mine? Can lenses solve my problem in a way that avoids those problems?)

(The functions I mentioned would look something like this.)

```
convert_0_1_2 :: State (a, b) x -> State (a, b, c) x
convert_0_1_2 f = do
    (a, b, c) <- get
    let (x, (a', b')) = runState f (a, b)
    put (a', b', c)
    return x

convert_0_2_1_0 :: State (c, b) x -> State (a, b, c, d) x
convert_0_2_1_0 f = do
    (a, b, c, d) <- get
    let (x, (b', c')) = runState f (b, c)
    put (a, b', c', d)
    return x
```

Comment: I have not used it myself, but it sounds very much like `lens`’s `zoom`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#v:zoom

Comment: That should be easy with dependent types, but not hasochistic.

Comment: `lens` + [`vinyl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl) makes for a halfway decent hasochistic experience.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it by using zoom from [`lens-family`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-family-1.2.0/docs/Lens-Family2-State-Lazy.html#v:zoom) or the [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#v:zoom) package with the [`tuple-lenses`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-lenses-0.1.0.2/docs/Data-Tuple-Lens.html) package: the simplified type of `zoom` is:

```
zoom :: Lens' s a -> State a x -> State s x
```

So `zoom` runs a computation using a smaller state. The `Lens` is used to specify the location of smaller state `a` inside the larger state `s`.

With these two packages, you can run `g`, `h` and `i` as follows:

```
f :: State (A,B,C) x
f = do
  zoom _12 g -- _12 :: Lens' (A,B,C) (A,B)
  zoom _23 h -- _23 :: Lens' (A,B,C) (B,C)
  zoom _13 i -- _13 :: Lens' (A,B,C) (A,C)
```

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I was aiming for :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to fuss around with tuples, you can use a "classy" approach with a record. There's some fancy Template Haskell to support this in the `lens` package, but you can also do it by hand. The idea is to create at least one class for each piece of the state:

```
class HasPoints s where
  points :: Lens' s Int

class ReadsPoints s where
  getPoints :: Getter s Int
  default getPoints :: HasPoints s => Getter s Int
  getPoints = points

class SetsPoints s where
  setPoints :: Setter' s Int
  ...
```

Then each function that manipulates the state will have a type signature like

```
fight :: (HasPoints s, ReadsHealth s) => StateT s Game Player
```

An action with this particular signature has full access to the points, and read-only access to the health.

Comment: Common use case of mine: `f :: State (A, A) ()` and `g :: State A ()`. Within `f`, I want to be able to call `g` on either the first or the second piece of `f`'s state. `g` should not know which of those two pieces is being passed into it. `g` should not even know it is part of a bigger application. But with the classy solution, `f` and `g` would have the same state type (a `Game` value) and use the same getters/setters to access any given piece of that state, right? While that lets me hide information from a function with few responsibilities, it seems to make my functions unreusable.